# Passing values to a viewmodel where the view doesn't exist

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm learning MVVM using MVVMLight and I've got a few screens working fine, the issue I have come up with is I'm trying to pass an object to another viewmodel which works fine, though when the view gets initalised, it appears to attach to a different instance of the viewmodel, so it's only when I change the view and then reload the form does it work as intended.

**SendingViewModel**

```
 MessengerInstance.Send(Messaging.FormChanged.SMSMessageInput);
            MessengerInstance.Send(SMSEmployees, Messaging.MessengerTokens.SMSMessageEmployees);
```

**RecViewModel**

```
 public SMSMessageInputViewModel()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<ObservableCollection<HRRM>>(this,Messaging.MessengerTokens.SMSMessageEmployees, value => Employees =value);
            MessageChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(MessageChanged);
        }
```

**ViewModelLocator**

```
public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        //Other Code
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SMSMessageInputViewModel>();
    }

public SMSMessageInputViewModel SMSMessageInput
        {
            get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SMSMessageInputViewModel>(); }
        }
```

I found changing

```
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SMSMessageInputViewModel>();
```

to

```
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SMSMessageInputViewModel>(true);
```

fixes the issue, but I don't want to generate this when the software opens because they may never use this part.

Comment: Speaking in very strict MVVM terms, the appearance of the ViewModel should triger the appeareance of the Window that displays it. The Window is simply the part of the view, that displays this specific sub-viewmodel from the Application View Model. The view would need to register a PropertyChange event on the ApplicationVM that exposes this "VM that appears in a Window". And disply/close the window accordingly. Of course a Framework like MVVM light might have another approach to this particular problem (dispalying parts of the VM in a seperate Window).

Comment: Apparently MVVM light has a messenger Class just for these Circumstances: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/637c0b5d-5e1d-48f2-a329-63c233e1451f/launching-a-new-window-from-a-viewmodel-on-a-button-click-in-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: Hi Chris, that is what I'm using above, except the instance has been created. So it sends it, but then it just fails as a new ViewModel is initialized.

Comment: How should the Window know the exposed ViewModel changed? Does the Property it is exposed on implement change notifcation? Has the view properly registered the change notificaiton event (via a binding)? Is the ApplicationViewModel instantaited where the Window can access it (Application Resouces)? One of those must not be true.